# JavaScript not executing file in models folder

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have generated an app using strongloop and added the following code in user.js

```
// user.js
console.log("came here");
module.exports = function(app) {
  console.log(app);
};
```

Why I cannot see any console? Why is this file not being included while running the server?

Comment: Where is user.js being included?

Comment: I am using loopback. I suppose all the files in models will be included directly

Comment: Can you try as,
    `console.log("came here");
    module.exports = function(user) {
      console.log(user.app);
    };`

Comment: it is a variable name, I have tried that too. No change.

Comment: Is this model extended off the built-in User model, or are you trying to add a user.js to affect the built-in model? If it's the latter, that does not work. You need to create a new model (e.g. customer) that has the built-in User as its base model, then create customer.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using user instead of User I am assuming you extended the default User class (case sensitive). If not, you have to https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Customizing+models

Some examples use "user" which is an extended "User" class but I always use a different name to prevent confusion (such as mentionned by @amuramoto, customer)

1. Check that you have a models/your_user_class.json
2. Check that your user class is in /server/model-config.json
3. Add your js file (beware the case) in models/your_user_class.js

Note that in `module.exports = function(app)`, app will be the model. Rename this way `module.exports = function(Customer)` (for example) and access the app object with `Customer.app`